# installing software via preference menu

Tags: software-installation

Complete newbie with Linux and everything Raspberry Pi, was given B+ starter kit and trying to install libre office from the Preference menu. I found the software and downloaded it but it requires a password. Where do i get the password from?

Thanks

Comment: In the Preference menu, you should select "Add/Remove Recommended Software", then you can select the packages (out of about 20) to install.  No password is necessary.  But if you select the "Add/Remove Software" option, then you need to select from a long list of packages, or use searching window.  Then you might be asked for a password.  The pass word is "raspberry", if you have not changed it during installation.  See the bottom of my answer.

Answer (score 4):

I assume you are using the Raspbian operating system. I don't know how do you download **Libre Office** but with Raspbian you should use its default repository. Then there is no password needed and there is no need to configure the software so it fits to Raspbian. That's all done with the installation from the repository. First you should update your system with:

```
rpi ~$ sudo apt update
rpi ~$ sudo apt full-upgrade
rpi ~$ sudo systemctl reboot
```

You can look what packages are available in the repository with:

```
rpi ~$ apt list libreoffice*
```

and will find 183 packages. That's much but most of them are only language packages to support specific languages for the surface. Just install

```
rpi ~$ sudo apt install libreoffice
```

This has default language US english. To install for example the language pack for british english:

```
rpi ~$ sudo apt install libreoffice-l10n-en-gb
```

Select your own language pack. Now you should have a working **Libre Office** installation.

Comment: Thanks I used preferred software and it loaded straight away

Answer (score 0):

***Question***

> trying to install libre office from the Preference menu.
>
> I found the software and downloaded it but it requires a password.
>
> Where do i get the password from?

***Answer***

That is strange, I have been downloading recommended software every time I installed a new Raspbian version.  ***But I have never been asked to give any password.***

Some days ago I installed *Raspbian stretch version 2019 April 08*, but surprisingly and sadly could not find the LibreOffice which used to be there.  So I need to download this "recommended software" but not preinstalled in the fullist image!

I am a GUI guy, so I used the desktop to do the job, as briefly summarized below:

> 1. Click Rpi logo/icon at the top right corner >
> 2. Preferences >
> 3. Recommended software (***not Add/Remove software!, see Note 1 below***) >
> 4. Updated package date, please wait >
> 5. Recommended software list (abount 20 packages, including LibreOffice)
> 6. Tick what you wish to install, but do NOT untick what you still want! Otherwise will be removed >
> 7. Clink OK, will see "Downloading xxx, please wait" >
> 8. Back to desktop, should find the LibreOffice icon etc

The picture below showed the 3 big steps I followed.

[image: rpi download]

***Note 1***

If you install software using "add/remove software", then you might be asked to give a password.  This is the password you entered when installing the OS.  ***If you did not change the default, then it is"raspberry".***

[image: add software]

Comment: Thanks for answering,  I too am a GUI user, do not understand anything to do with the root menu or script. But followed your instructions and loaded perfectly.

Comment: How nice to hear the good news.  You reminded me a couple of years ago, when I first tried Rpi 1, whose GUI was very very slow, and could do many things in terminal mode.  So I was forced to learn the scary commands sudo, nano, tar, and other cripic bash commands.  I remember once it took me 3 long, sweating hours to do something with wget and tar.  One reason is that I don't know that some file names must use a prefix ".\", and that some file/folder names are "virtual" or "alias" , meaning that you cannot use directory tools to find them, ...：( Now using GUI drag and drop - only 3 SECONDS!!!